# .net core 5 app blocking due to CORS policy

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have created an api using .net core 5.0 but no matter what I do it seems to block my request to it giving the error

```
    has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

my code in my startup.cs is

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyCorsPolicy", policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
        });
        services.AddTransient<IChatLog, LogsData>(provider => new LogsData());
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

From what I have read that should allow any requests from anywhere, but for some reason it is still blocking.

Has anyone any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `app.UseCors()` did not specify a policy name. You can add the name `AllowAnyCorsPolicy`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        app.UseCors("AllowAnyCorsPolicy");
        //...
    }
```

Comment: @andrew slaughter, can this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyCorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

and this too:

```
  app.UseCors("AllowAnyCorsPolicy");
```